# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property -> Geofire with Ionic 2 Rc2 + Firebase 3

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, ionic2, geofire

I am working on a mobile app (using Ionic 2 RC0) which is succesfully connected to Firebase.

Messages are sent and retrieved from firebase, but now I want to geolocate them so users get only nearby messages, for that I'm using Geofire.

My code goes as follows:

```
getGeolocation(): void {
    this.platform.ready().then(
      () => Geolocation.getCurrentPosition().then(
        location => this.saveGeolocation(location)  
      )
    )
  }

 saveGeolocation(location): void{
    console.log(location); //works
    var usersRef =  firebase.database().ref('users/geofire');
    console.log(usersRef.toString()); //works 
    var geoFire = new GeoFire(usersRef); // <-- ERROR (See below)
    geoFire.set('geolocation', [location.coords.latitude,location.coords.longitude])
 }
```

**The error I get is:**
*EXCEPTION: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: a.GeoFire is not a constructor*

My dependencies at package.json are:

```
"dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "2.1.1",
    "@angular/compiler": "2.1.1",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "2.1.1",
    "@angular/core": "2.1.1",
    "@angular/forms": "2.1.1",
    "@angular/http": "2.1.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "2.1.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "2.1.1",
    "@angular/platform-server": "2.1.1",
    "@ionic/app-scripts": "0.0.37-5",
    "@ionic/storage": "1.1.6",
    "angularfire2": "^2.0.0-beta.6",
    "es6-promise": "^4.0.5",
    "es6-shim": "^0.35.1",
    "es7-reflect-metadata": "^1.6.0",
    "firebase": "^3.6.1",
    "geofire": "^4.1.2",
    "ionic-angular": "2.0.0-rc.2",
    "ionic-native": "2.2.3",
    "ionicons": "3.0.0",
    "rxjs": "5.0.0-beta.12",
    "zone.js": "0.6.21"
  }
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: this answer *might* be usefull http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39054386/using-geofire-in-an-angular2-app

Comment: I just posted an answer at http://stackoverflow.com/a/41072056/370532 that should help you.