# Using GeoFire in Angular2-cli app which uses WebPack instead of System.config.js

Tags: angularjs, angular, typescript, angular-cli, geofire

I am new to typescript and facing this issue , the answer to this question is perfectly given in another question but i have no clue how to do this in web pack because the solution provided to that answer was of System.config.js and i an not having it in my project.
here is the link to that question if one can solve the System.config.js part.

[Using GeoFire in an Angular2 App](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39054386/using-geofire-in-an-angular2-app)

Answer (score 0):

Ran into the same issue and solved it using webpack expose loader:

[Expose Loader](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/expose-loader)

First add this to your bundle (vendor.ts):

```
require("expose?GeoFire!geofire");
```

Then add this to your loaders in webpack.config.js:

```
module: {
  loaders: [
    { test: require.resolve('geofire'), loader: 'expose?GeoFire' }
  ]
}
```

Finally in your Component:

```
declare var GeoFire: any;
```